# how can I update a single cell in wix dataset

Tags: velo

So Ive created a wix website for bus trafic (like moovit app) and Ive tryed to add a "real time report" function (so users will be able to report when a bus is arrived at real time).

my problem is that no matter what I try I cant update my dataset!

lets say I have 3 stations: station1,station2,station3
when I update the arrival time of station3 my wix decides to to copy the whole station3 row into startion1 without updating the field I wanted.

can someone give ame a working update function?

here is my code:(the update part comes after "console.log("1")")

```
export function button1_click(event) {
 let stationIndex = $w("#stationDropDown").selectedIndex;
console.log($w("#stationDropDown").selectedIndex);
$w("#dataset1").getItems(0, 12).then((data) => {
    var currStation = data.items[$w("#stationDropDown").selectedIndex];
    console.log(currStation);
    let arrivalsArray = currStation.arrivals;
    let rt_arrivalsArray = currStation.rtArrivals;
    let reporteTimes = currStation.reporteTimes;
    if(arrivalsArray.length!==rt_arrivalsArray.length || reporteTimes.length!==rt_arrivalsArray.length)
    {
        console.log("there is a length problem in the station database:"+arrivalsArray.length+","+rt_arrivalsArray.length+","+reporteTimes.length);
        return;
    }
    let closestArrivalIndex = getClosestArrivalIndex(arrivalsArray);
    console.log("closestArrivalIndex=" + closestArrivalIndex);
    var now = new Date();
    if (now.getMinutes() < 10)
        currStation.rtArrivals[closestArrivalIndex] = now.getHours() + ":0" + now.getMinutes();
    else
        currStation.rtArrivals[closestArrivalIndex] = now.getHours() + ":" + now.getMinutes();
    if(reporteTimes.length>closestArrivalIndex)
    {
        if(reporteTimes[closestArrivalIndex]==="")
            currStation.reporteTimes[closestArrivalIndex]=0;
        currStation.reporteTimes[closestArrivalIndex]++;
    }
    console.log("1");
    let toUpdate = {
    "rtArrivals":        currStation.rtArrivals,
    "reporteTimes":   currStation.reporteTimes,
    };
    wixData.update("dataset1", toUpdate);
    $w("#dataset1").save(currStation);
    console.log("done reporting");
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

solved it myself:

```
`//name of database = "stuff"
//row ID = <record id>

wixData.get("Stuff", <record id>)
.then((toUpdate) => {
   toUpdate.fld = "x";
   wixData.update("Stuff", toUpdate)
   .then((result) => {
      // updated object returned so let's take a look
      console.log(result);
   })
   .catch((err) => {
      let errorMsg = err;
   });
})
.catch((err) => {
   let errorMsg = err;
});`
```